# Send escape character to printer

Tags: c#, .net, string, printing, thermal-printer

I am developing an C# application to print labels from a thermal transfer printer from SATO (CG408 TT)

For this I am using SBPL (Programming language for SATO). Which looks something like following:

```
<ESC>A
<ESC>H0050<ESC>V0100<ESC>L0303<ESC>XMSATO
<ESC>H0050<ESC>V0200<ESC>B103100*SATO*
<ESC>H0070<ESC>V0310<ESC>L0101<ESC>XUSATO
<ESC>Q1<ESC>Z
```

To communicate with Printer and send raw data to it I am following [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322091) technique.  At first i am trying to build the escape sequences using StringBuilder Class.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
              sb.AppendLine();
              sb.AppendLine("<ESC>A");
              sb.AppendLine("H0050<ESC>V0100<ESC>L0303<ESC>XMSATO");
```

and so on....

But how can I replace `<ESC>` part in string builder argument. I know that character 27, but then how to use it with AppendLine Command

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
const char ESC = '\x1B';
```

now you can use ESC like any other variable. Note that you can embed esc in a string as well: `"\x1B"` but I suppose that would become unwieldy (especially with adjacent numbers).

Please do *not* `ESC + "somestring" + ESC` etc. because it defeats the purpose of the StringBuilder

You could

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
          sb.AppendLine();
          sb.AppendLine("<ESC>A");
          sb.AppendLine("H0050<ESC>V0100<ESC>L0303<ESC>XMSATO");
String output = sb.ToString().Replace("<ESC>", "\x1B")
```

e.g.

Comment: So can I do

const char ESC = '\x1F';

sb.AppendLine(ESC+"A");

Comment: @sehe: what you've added to your post doesn't make sense now :)

Comment: @sehe: I've seen it unformatted, it's ok now. Btw, it's OK to do `ESC + "somestring" + ESC`, it gets optimised by compiler. `StringBuilder` is useful in looping scenarios.

Comment: @sehe: String output = sb.ToString().Replace("<ESC>", "\x1B") looks much better... !!

Comment: @sehe: "because it defaults the purpose of the StringBuilder": I think it defeats the purpose, not defaults it.

Comment: @sehe: I will accept this as an answer as an when I test it with printer :) Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
sb.AppendLine(((char)27).ToString());
```

Comment: Yes your method is perfect, but then I have multiple lines and so many times ESC within a single line. Is the method suggested by @sehe is better ? 
I mean can I do:
const char ESC = '\x1F';
sb.AppendLine(ESC+"A");

Comment: @Niraj Doshi: it's better for readability and no need for casting (although the compiler may optimize this, not sure).

Comment: Yes obviously you should create a constant, that's just basic; the question wasn't about coding practices, it was about how to get the escape character. Casting from 27 seemed to make sense because you knew that the character code was 27.

Answer (score 1):

For OPOS Drivers, I ended up using

```
string ESC = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(new byte[] { 27 });
```