# SATO USB printing in C#

Tags: c#, usb, barcode-printing

I have been trying to print to a SATO GL408e printer.  I am trying to send the data via USB interface but have no example code to do that with.  I tried to use the example code from here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322091 but it runs with no errors and no printing. Does anyone out there know how to send the data to the SATO printer?

Thanks!

(Here is the code I am using)

```
private void PrintLabels_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string PrintCommand = "";

    string EmployeeNo = EmployeeList.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    string YearNumber = EmployeeList.SelectedRows[0].Cells[7].Value.ToString();
    string FirstTraceCode = (int.Parse(EmployeeList.SelectedRows[0].Cells[5].Value.ToString()) + 1).ToString();
    string SecondTraceCode = (int.Parse(EmployeeList.SelectedRows[0].Cells[5].Value.ToString()) + 2).ToString();
    string LabelQuantity = "15";

    MessageBox.Show(EmployeeNo.Substring(0, 2) + "-" + EmployeeNo.Substring(2, 4) + "-" + YearNumber + "-" + FirstTraceCode);
    PrintCommand = "\x02\x1bA\x1bIG1\x1bZ\x03\x02\x1bA\x1b#E3\x1bZ\x03\x02\x1bA\x1bCS5\x1bZ\x03\x02\x1bA\x1bEX0\x1bZ\x03\x02\x1bA\x1b*&\x1bZ\x03\x02\x1bA\x1bA3H0001V0001\x1bZ\x03\x02\x1bA\x1bV0000\x1bH0259\x1bF001+002\x1bD202099" + EmployeeNo + YearNumber + FirstTraceCode + "\x1bL0203\x1bH0247\x1bV0114\x1bF001+002\x1bU" + EmployeeNo.Substring(0, 2) + "-" + EmployeeNo.Substring(2, 4) + "-" + YearNumber + "-" + FirstTraceCode + "\x1bV0000\x1bH0589\x1bF001+002\x1bD202099" + EmployeeNo + YearNumber + SecondTraceCode + "\x1bL0203\x1bH0577\x1bV0114\x1bF001+002\x1bU" + EmployeeNo.Substring(0, 2) + "-" + EmployeeNo.Substring(2, 4) + "-" + YearNumber + "-" + SecondTraceCode + "\x1bQ" + LabelQuantity + "\x1b 00\x1bZ\x03   ";
    // Allow the user to select a printer.
    PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();
    pd.PrinterSettings = new PrinterSettings();
    if (DialogResult.OK == pd.ShowDialog(this))
    {
        // Print the file to the printer.
        RawPrinterHelper.SendStringToPrinter(pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName, PrintCommand);
    }
}

public class RawPrinterHelper
{
    // Structure and API declarions:
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public class DOCINFOA
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
        public string pDocName;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
        public string pOutputFile;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
        public string pDataType;
    }

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "OpenPrinterA", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool OpenPrinter([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string szPrinter, out IntPtr hPrinter, IntPtr pd);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "ClosePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool ClosePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "StartDocPrinterA", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool StartDocPrinter(IntPtr hPrinter, Int32 level, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] DOCINFOA di);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "EndDocPrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool EndDocPrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "StartPagePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool StartPagePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "EndPagePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool EndPagePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "WritePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool WritePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter, IntPtr pBytes, Int32 dwCount, out Int32 dwWritten);

    // SendBytesToPrinter()
    // When the function is given a printer name and an unmanaged array
    // of bytes, the function sends those bytes to the print queue.
    // Returns true on success, false on failure.
    public static bool SendBytesToPrinter(string szPrinterName, IntPtr pBytes, Int32 dwCount)
    {
        Int32 dwError = 0, dwWritten = 0;
        IntPtr hPrinter = new IntPtr(0);
        DOCINFOA di = new DOCINFOA();
        bool bSuccess = false; // Assume failure unless you specifically succeed.

        di.pDocName = "My C#.NET RAW Document";
        di.pDataType = "RAW";

        try
        {
            // Open the printer.
            if (OpenPrinter(szPrinterName.Normalize(), out hPrinter, IntPtr.Zero))
            {
                // Start a document.
                if (StartDocPrinter(hPrinter, 1, di))
                {
                    // Start a page.
                    if (StartPagePrinter(hPrinter))
                    {
                        // Write your bytes.
                        bSuccess = WritePrinter(hPrinter, pBytes, dwCount, out dwWritten);
                        EndPagePrinter(hPrinter);
                    }
                    EndDocPrinter(hPrinter);
                }
                ClosePrinter(hPrinter);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        // If you did not succeed, GetLastError may give more information
        // about why not.
        if (bSuccess == false)
        {
            dwError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
        }
        return bSuccess;
    }

    public static bool SendFileToPrinter(string szPrinterName, string szFileName)
    {
        // Open the file.
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(szFileName, FileMode.Open);
        // Create a BinaryReader on the file.
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
        // Dim an array of bytes big enough to hold the file's contents.
        Byte[] bytes = new Byte[fs.Length];
        bool bSuccess = false;
        // Your unmanaged pointer.
        IntPtr pUnmanagedBytes = new IntPtr(0);
        int nLength;

        nLength = Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length);
        // Read the contents of the file into the array.
        bytes = br.ReadBytes(nLength);
        // Allocate some unmanaged memory for those bytes.
        pUnmanagedBytes = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(nLength);
        // Copy the managed byte array into the unmanaged array.
        Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, pUnmanagedBytes, nLength);
        // Send the unmanaged bytes to the printer.
        bSuccess = SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, pUnmanagedBytes, nLength);
        // Free the unmanaged memory that you allocated earlier.
        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pUnmanagedBytes);
        return bSuccess;
    }

    public static bool SendStringToPrinter(string szPrinterName, string szString)
    {
        IntPtr pBytes;
        Int32 dwCount;
        // How many characters are in the string?
        dwCount = szString.Length;
        // Assume that the printer is expecting ANSI text, and then convert
        // the string to ANSI text.
        pBytes = Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemAnsi(szString);
        // Send the converted ANSI string to the printer.
        SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, pBytes, dwCount);
        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pBytes);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5514815/send-escape-character-to-printer

Comment: Unfortunately I have already reviewed that article.  It helped me build out my printer command strings, but does not help me get the commands to the printer.  Thanks for the try though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved this issue.  The Microsoft code worked great.  The issue was with the string I was sending to the printer.  The escape codes were not working.  Instead I replaced the escape codes with the command names and then did a substitute with characters.  Thanks to all who attempted to help!

Here is the code I replaced:

```
PrintCommand = "<STX><ESC>A<ESC>IG1<ESC>Z<ETX><STX><ESC>A<ESC>#E3<ESC>Z<ETX><STX><ESC>A<ESC>CS5<ESC>Z<ETX><STX><ESC>A<ESC>EX0<ESC>Z<ETX><STX><ESC>A<ESC>*&<ESC>Z<ETX><STX><ESC>A<ESC>A3H0001V0001<ESC>Z<ETX><STX><ESC>A<ESC>V0000<ESC>H0259<ESC>F001+002<ESC>D202099" + EmployeeNo + YearNumber + FirstTraceCode + "<ESC>L0203<ESC>H0247<ESC>V0114<ESC>F001+002<ESC>U" + EmployeeNo.Substring(0, 2) + "-" + EmployeeNo.Substring(2, 4) + "-" + YearNumber + "-" + FirstTraceCode + "<ESC>V0000<ESC>H0589<ESC>F001+002<ESC>D202099" + EmployeeNo + YearNumber + SecondTraceCode + "<ESC>L0203<ESC>H0577<ESC>V0114<ESC>F001+002<ESC>U" + EmployeeNo.Substring(0, 2) + "-" + EmployeeNo.Substring(2, 4) + "-" + YearNumber + "-" + SecondTraceCode + "<ESC>Q" + LabelQuantity + "<ESC>00<ESC>Z<ETX>";
PrintCommand = PrintCommand.Replace("<STX>", ((char)02).ToString());
PrintCommand = PrintCommand.Replace("<ETX>", ((char)03).ToString());
PrintCommand = PrintCommand.Replace("<ESC>", ((char)27).ToString());
```

Comment: I tried with the code as mentioned. The code runs without any error. But the printer doesn't print. Could you tell me what else need to be done other than this code?

Comment: It is likely that the string you are sending to the printer is incorrectly formatted.  Much like my issue, I had been sending the \ codes.  I had to change it to the code above to make it work.

Comment: I just used your code with my sample data (PrintCommand) instead of the variables you have used which results in the "AIG1ZA#E3ZACS5ZAEX0ZA*&ZAA3H0001V0001ZAV0000H0259F001+002D202099MyCode123L0203H0247V0114F001+002UMyNumber123V0000H0589F001+002D202099MyString1L0203H0577V0114F001+002UMyStringQ100Z". Could you help me if this is wrong and correct me?

Comment: I don't know the actual string you need to use.  If it is a sato printer, it should use a command like the one in the solution.  If not, I cannot say for sure.